# Why remove dependency from java.awt?

Tags: java, dependencies

In Selenium's [Point class Javadocs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Point.html), it states that it is:

> A copy of java.awt.Point, to remove dependency on awt.

What is gained by this?

Comment: Eliminating a dependency on Java UI classes. Before Java 9, this makes it easier to verify that the product is not coupling to a different UI toolkit. In Java 9, that might allow running in a JVM without Java UI classes.

Comment: @AndyThomas, is there something in Java 9, then, that would allow a conforming Java implementation to fail to provide the AWT, or other parts of the Java SE standard library?

Comment: @AndyThomas Then, what is gained by that ease in verification?

Comment: @skia.heliou - More confidence that a second UI toolkit is not being used accidentally. And later, with Java 9, easy decoupling from the corresponding module -- `java.desktop`.

Comment: @AndyThomas, you and DCON - both good and interesting points. This isn't one of those cases in which I'm fond of making my own answer based on what others have suggested, so the first of you two to get all information in one answer gets the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you wanted to import the entire selenium class, you'd do something like this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
```

If you wanted to use point, then you'd also have to do:

```
import java.awt.point;
```

even if you weren't going to use any other part of the `java.awt` package.

So, by doing this, you never have to include `java.awt` unless explicitly using it- hence, no dependency on `java.awt`.

This was probably done because AWT is known to run differently on different platforms, which defeats one of the key philosophies of Java- WORA (Write Once Run Anywhere). You don't want something that's supposed to be platform independent like Selenium to depend on something heavyweight like AWT.